# Laravel 8 will auto convert date into UTC

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

```
$lastLoggedActivity = User::get();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($lastLoggedActivity);
        echo "</pre>";
```

**Output**

[image]

**If data convert to array**

```
$lastLoggedActivity = User::get()->toArray();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($lastLoggedActivity);
        echo "</pre>";
```

**Output**

[image]

Database record

[image]

Question: Does anyone facing this issue in laravel 8, once convert the data into array, the date format will auto convert into UTC, even I already set the timezone in app.php into "Asia/Singapore", but it will auto convert as well. How can I get the date which is exactly like the database instead of auto convert into utc format?

Comment: Since created_at and updated_at are timestamps they will always be converted to UTC in the database. This is so you don't end up storing the wrong time (since database timestamps don't store timezone information). When Laravel retrieves the model the data is a Carbon instance. When you dump the value then you get a default serialized value which is the time in UTC. Try doing `dd(User::first()->created_at->toDateTimeLocalString())` and check if that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add it to your User model:

```php
/**
 * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
 *
 * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
 * @return string
 */
protected function serializeDate(\DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```